# cakephp email issue with some domains

Tags: email, cakephp, smtp

I have cakephp application, and it has no domain name we are accessing using ip.
I am using the following smpt setting to send email

```
class EmailConfig {

public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('myemail@otherdomain.com' => 'my name'),
    'host' => 'mail.otherdomain.com',//not the same domain from which sending email
    'port' => 25,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'myemail@otherdomain.com',
    'password' => 'password',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false,
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
  );
}
```

all emails are being sent to any_email @ gmail, otherdomain etc
but there is only one specific govt domain(abc.gov.com) who are not receiving email
they may have implemented some security measures, which may prevent my emails to them, what things can I try at my side and how can I debug to get exact error.
I tried to send email where
`to = email@abc.gov.com`
`cc = email@otherdomain.com`
the same email is being received by `email@otherdomain.com` while not by `email@abc.gov.com`

Comment: Check your mail server logs to see if the e-mail was at all offered to and accepted by the remote mail server.

Comment: where can i see mail server log

Comment: That depends on your setup. Most Linux servers have it under `/var/log/mail.log` or `/var/log/maillog`.

Comment: I noticed that the email is returning on $Emial->return='my_email@domain.com' without any error. dot know how to reach the error